# unblind click doesn't work in my case to remove click event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to stop the click event from firing but it doesn't work in my case.

html

```
<div class="owl-controls clickable"><div class="owl-buttons"><div class="owl-prev disabled"><i class="navigator fa fa-caret-left"></i></div><span class="pagi">1/2</span><div class="owl-next"><i class="navigator fa fa-caret-right"></i></div></div></div>
```

myjs

```
$(".fa-caret-right").click(function(){
    $(".pagi").text("2\/2");
    $(this).unbind("click");
});
```

I tried return false it doesn't stop too, maybe because owl-carosel has it click event fired.

Comment: "*I want to stop the click event from firing but it doesn't work in my case*" - if you don't want it to fire, then why did you write one..?!! What do you mean by *"owl-carosel has it click event fired"* ? What exactly are you trying to do..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can also use this after on click off the click event

[**Js Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/victor_007/dk55trnd/)

```
$('.fa-caret-right').on('click', function() {
   $(".pagi").text("2\/2");
   $(this).off('click')
});
```

Comment: is there any different in off() and unblind() ??

Answer (score 1):

if you want it to be clickable only once then go for [.one](http://api.jquery.com/one/) as shown below :-

```
$(".fa-caret-right").one("click", function(){
    $(".pagi").text("2\/2");

});
```

**Description**:

Attach a handler to an event for the elements. The handler is executed at most once per element per event type.